# Used 12 word recovery seed phrase to restore wallet, then remembered my password to the old wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I can now log in using both the old wallet id and password for one, and the new wallet id and password for the other. Both wallets have the same funds from various crypto currencies. Is there a way to consolidate both, or get rid of one of them somehow? Are they still the same wallet with more than one wallet identifier?

Comment: What wallet software are you using?

Comment: blockchain. Will this be moot when I receive my nano-s cold storage and start using it?

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a way to consolidate both**

If both wallets have the same keys and same balances there is nothing to consolidate, wallets are essentially a store of private-keys and a means to view the common blockchain.

You don't need to consolidate a wallet and it's duplicate.

> **or get rid of one of them somehow?**

You need to be careful when deleting one if both are on the same computer - especially if both are the same software. The exact answer may depend on what wallet software you use.

I would use the wallet software's facilities to delete one wallet, then use normal tools to wipe clean unused disk space.

Since you have a proven recovery method, you should be OK. At worst you repeat the recovery process (on a new computer if necessary).